# python: read a file on each line and store only ints into list

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I read a file which looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Then I read this lines into list:

```
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4']
```

My question is, how and what is the best way to get ints and store them into list, without any strings or this '\n'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    nums = [int(i.strip()) for i in f.readlines()]

>>> print nums
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: @Xerath, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you